# How can I access the snapshot for global variable

Tags: angular, firebase-realtime-database

Here is the function I am using for accessing the firebase data.

```
export class SubscriptionProductComponent implements OnInit {

  private products: any;
  private customer: any;

  constructor(private database: AngularFireDatabase,private route: Router) { 
      this.customer = this.database.database.ref().child('/Products/');

    this.customer.orderByChild("productType").equalTo("subscription").on('value', function (snapshot) {
      console.log(snapshot.toJSON());
      this.products = snapshot.toJSON();
      console.log(this.products);
    });
 }

  ngOnInit() {}

  //Some other function are here
}
```

I am getting the error that

```
core.js:6210 ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'products' of undefined
    at subscription-product.component.ts:34
    at valueCallback (index.esm.js:14463)
    at CallbackContext.push.6Uf2.CallbackContext.onValue (index.esm.js:12274)
    at index.esm.js:13118
    at exceptionGuard (index.esm.js:638)
    at eventListRaise (index.esm.js:11082)
    at eventQueueRaiseQueuedEventsMatchingPredicate (index.esm.js:11057)
    at eventQueueRaiseEventsForChangedPath (index.esm.js:11044)
    at repoOnDataUpdate (index.esm.js:11261)
    at PersistentConnection.repo.server_ [as onDataUpdate_] (index.esm.js:11163)
```

Please help me with this one.

Comment: Where you you define `this.products`? It seems that there is no variable named `products`.

Comment: It is at the beginning of the code right after the class declaration as usually, we do.

Comment: Does `console.log(snapshot.toJSON());` produce any output?

Comment: yes, @Lynx242 console.log(snapshot.toJSON()); returns the exact output as it needs to be. But the problem is how can I access it globally?

Comment: ‘this’ inside the callback (this.products) is not what you expect it to be. Change the function in the callback to an arrow and you should be fine. function (snapshot) Should be (snapshot) =>

Comment: Sorry @MikeOne. I was actually typing the same while you already answered.

Comment: No problemo !

Comment: Thank you very much guys, this was an easy solution but wasted hours debugging on this. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it with an arrow function:

```
this.customer.orderByChild("productType").equalTo("subscription").on('value', (snapshot) => {
  console.log(snapshot.toJSON());
  this.products = snapshot.toJSON();
  console.log(this.products);
});
```

Comment: It worked with the arrow function buddy. Thank You very much @Lynx242